# Combining and editing two lists in python

Tags: python

I have two lists with the exact same lengths. 
First list is one with just numbers(Percentages)
Second list is a little more complex. It has the same amount of Elements as the first one, but each element consists of multiple strings, separated by semicolon.

```
percList = ['40%', '30%', '20%', '10%']
sportName = ['Football;Football;Fuball;Futbol;Calcio','Basketball;Basketball;Basketball;Baloncesto;Pallacanestro',
'Baseball;Base-Ball;Baseball;Béisbol,', 'Rugby;Le Rugby;Rugby;Rugby;Rugby',]
```

What I need to do is to combine these two lists to one - and add percentages in front of each language. Each percentage from the first list should go with to the same indexed element on the second list. The output I'm looking for is:

```
combinedList = ['
40% Football;40% Football;40% Fuball;40% Futbol;40% Calcio,
30% Basketball;30% Basketball;30% Basketball;30% Baloncesto;30% Pallacanestro,
20% Baseball;20% Base-Ball;20% Baseball;20% Béisbol,
10% Rugby;10% Le Rugby;10% Rugby;10% Rugby;10% Rugby
']
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> [';'.join([i+' '+x for x in j.split(';')]) for i, j in zip(percList,sportName)]
# or,
>>> [';'.join(map(lambda x:i+' '+x,j.split(';'))) for i, j in zip(percList,sportName)]
['40% Football;40% Football;40% Fuball;40% Futbol;40% Calcio',
 '30% Basketball;30% Basketball;30% Basketball;30% Baloncesto;30% Pallacanestro',
 '20% Baseball;20% Base-Ball;20% Baseball;20% Béisbol,',
 '10% Rugby;10% Le Rugby;10% Rugby;10% Rugby;10% Rugby']
```

EDIT:

```
percList = ['40%', '30%', '20%', '10%']
sportName = ['Football;Football;Fuball;Futbol;Calcio','Basketball;Basketball;Basketball;Baloncesto;Pallacanestro',
'Baseball;Base-Ball;Baseball;Béisbol,', 'Rugby;Le Rugby;Rugby;Rugby;Rugby']
new_lst = []
for i, j in zip(percList, sportName):

    elem = ';'.join(map(lambda x:i+' '+x,j.split(';')))
    new_lst.append(elem)
print(new_lst)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Added another method, should be slightly faster.

Comment: Andy chance you could write this code out in an expanded way: with indentation etc. its just a lot easier to read and will help me understand

Comment: Added what you asked, have a look. You may mark it as accepted if you find it the best answer according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Accurately with regex magic:

```
import re

perc_list = ['40%', '30%', '20%', '10%']
sport_names = ['Football;Football;Fuball;Futbol;Calcio', 'Basketball;Basketball;Basketball;Baloncesto;Pallacanestro',
               'Baseball;Base-Ball;Baseball;Béisbol,', 'Rugby;Le Rugby;Rugby;Rugby;Rugby']
pat = re.compile(r'(^|;)([a-z])', re.I)
res = [pat.sub(rf'\g<1>{p} \2', s_name) for p, s_name in zip(perc_list, sport_names)]

print(res)
```

The output:

```
['40% Football;40% Football;40% Fuball;40% Futbol;40% Calcio',
 '30% Basketball;30% Basketball;30% Basketball;30% Baloncesto;30% Pallacanestro',
 '20% Baseball;20% Base-Ball;20% Baseball;20% Béisbol,',
 '10% Rugby;10% Le Rugby;10% Rugby;10% Rugby;10% Rugby']
```